# Retain and a "singleton" property at once?

Tags: ios, singleton, retain

I want to declare my `property` as the following...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *phoneNumber;
```

But I also want to assign it an initial value during debugging such as (I don't want to input all the numbers manually)...

```
self.phoneNumber = @"123";
```

If I do as I have written, I must additionally somewhere retain this `property`. Could someone please help me achieve this.

Comment: Can't just use the property to set the value?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. In your view, what will go wrong when you do self.phoneNumber = @"123" ?

Comment: I'm sorry self.phoneNumber is correct. But the problem is if I use @"123" (or similar values) then my property works as a singleton: its retain count is always 0 before initialising and 1 after it. For example I can't to make retainCount == 2

Comment: It's not a singleton, @"123" is a string literal and is a static value. Don't worry about it's retain count.  The code above is perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should in `dealloc` method `release` all properties that has attribute `retain`. You can do it by `assigning` `nil` value to your objects via `self.` notation:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     self.phoneNumber = nil;

     [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `self.` in initialisers and dealloc. Also, you missed out the call to `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: Don't see any problem in using `self.`. `[super dealloc]` added

Comment: Nekto hasn't understood me. I want to change the code in one function only. So I still have only one solving - to use preprocessor #if 1 ... #else ... #endif or to comment one block and uncomment another via using /* ... //*/ which are almost the same things

Comment: And? My problem is that I must make 1 time more object releasings than in debug mode and I am asking for solving this problem. If you think that it is a newbie question then Why cannot you offer me anything better than my solving?